# do I need to worry about mysql connection pooling for node.js using sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling, sequelize.js

I'm new to node.js and have heard of connection pooling and it makes sense to me as the connection is an expensive operation.

I am looking at which node module to use for mysql and I like the look of Sequelize as it is an ORM.

I'm not sure if I need to worry about connection pooling with Sequelize. Do I just instantiate it and reuse it for all clients?

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username'[, 'password'])
```

Also, do I need to worry about the number of parallel queries being executed?

For example, if I am looping through a table and executing a query per row. What happens if there are 1000 or more rows?

Do those queries get executed all at once?

If so, is there a limit to the amount you can throw at it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

at the very moment Sequelize is not using pooling. This caused many problems in the past, so it was removed. I will add pooling again in later versions of Sequelize. At the moment, every request opens a new connection. There is also a known bug, which leads to unclosed connections. Due to heavy enhancements in the next version, this will hopefully be fixed. I will also change from the currently used node-mysql to another mysql connector, which is much faster. Once this is done, I try to add pooling again.

Comment: Thanks sdepold, what about the parallel queries, does it hammer the db?

Comment: Sequelize v3 does have connection pool: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v3/docs/docs/getting-started.md#setting-up-a-connection

Comment: can you please explain how to use pool ? is it necessary ? 
i cant understand the ussage in docs